# Digits iOS OAuthEcho Issue

Tags: ios, django, oauth, twitter-digits

I'm working on an iOS and django app that uses twitter digits for authentication. I've been sitting with the documentation for a while now and don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.

The communication model is that a user signs up on the iOS app powered by Twitter Digits. This sends a text message to the user with a confirmation code to verify the user's identity. When the user's identity is confirmed, I'd like for the iOS app to notify the server so that the server can create a new user model and securely store the user's phone number.

Currently, the response from twitter digits at Line 8 is:

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Things I've tried / done:

1) I've triple, quadruple checked that the consumer key, consumer secret, and API key match the app in Fabric.

2) Used different methods besides `OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials` including `OAuthEchoHeadersForRequestMethod` and `OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentialsWithParams`

3) Debugged with a web frontend that does work. This made it clear that the auth information sent by the ios app is wonky.

The backend code is as follows:

```
def signup(request):
    api_url = request.POST['apiUrl']
    auth_headers = request.POST['authHeader']

    # security stuff done here

    headers = {'Authorization': auth_headers}
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers) # Line 8
    data = json.loads(response.content)

    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
        phone_number=data['phone_number'],
        digits_id=data['id'],
        first_name=request.POST['firstName'],
        last_name=request.POST['lastName']
    )

    return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'created': created})
```

And the frontend code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func goToNextView() {
        let firstName = "Joe"
        let lastName = "Schmoe"

        let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
        digits.authenticateWithCompletion { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                let digits = Digits.sharedInstance()
                let oauthSigning = DGTOAuthSigning(authConfig: digits.authConfig, authSession: session)

                let authHeaders = oauthSigning.OAuthEchoHeadersToVerifyCredentials()

                let apiUrl = authHeaders[TWTROAuthEchoRequestURLStringKey]
                let authHeader = authHeaders[TWTROAuthEchoAuthorizationHeaderKey]

                let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/signup")

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

                let bodyData = "apiUrl=\(apiUrl!)&authHeader=\(authHeader!)&firstName=\(firstName)&lastName=\(lastName)"
                request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                self.defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                    print("todo")
                }).resume()                    
            }
        }
    }
```

For reference the web front end is as follows:

```
Digits.logIn()
  .done(onLogin) 

function onLogin(loginResponse){
  // Send headers to your server and validate user by calling Digits’ API
  var oAuthHeaders = loginResponse.oauth_echo_headers;
  var verifyData = {
    authHeader: oAuthHeaders['X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization'],
    apiUrl: oAuthHeaders['X-Auth-Service-Provider'],
    firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
    lastName: $('#lastName').val()
  };

  $.post('/signup', verifyData)
    .done(function(response){ alert(response); });
}
```

In the two frontends, the auth headers that are different are:
- oauth_nonce, oauth_signature, and obviously the oauth_timestamp

However, the two share:
- Oauth_consumer_key, oauth_token, version, and signature method

If anyone has encountered something similar before, please let me know. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, did you manage to figure this out? I'm able to successfully login using Digits but not sure how to get the userId, phoneNumber, etc. Been almost an year but still there's no other info available online... Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: @AhsasSharma, sadly no. I stopped working on this side project all together so don't have any help to offer. Best of luck!